# I am writing a quick web page using html and am running into syntax error

Tags: html, flask

I can't seem to find the error in the code, I am not very familiar with HTML. I keep getting a syntax error on line one:

```
    File "C:\Users\____\Desktop\Flask_test\index.html", line 1
        <html>
        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Home Page!</h1>
        <p>Hello!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This looks like a `SyntaxError` from the Python interpreter, as if you've run `python index.html`.  That won't work.  If that's the case, you need to write a valid python function which returns HTML.

Comment: Could you go more into depth on how I would go about doing this?

Comment: This is really basic stuff.  You may wish to have a look at Miguel's tutorial, which has a whole section on [templating](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-ii-templates).

Comment: Thank you I will check that out

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Flask but I believe it's requesting the !DOCTYPE at the beginning. Try adding <!DOCTYPE html> before the starting HTML tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` and improve the code's formatting.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <title>Home page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Home Page!</h1>
        <p>Hello!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried putting !DOCTYPE html at the start of the code and I am getting the same error message as before.

Comment: Are u using python and flask?

Comment: Yes I am trying to use python and flask

Comment: Which version of python do you have?

Comment: I am using Python version 3.7

Comment: Are u using Windows?

Comment: Yes I am on Windows 10

Comment: I am using Sublime Text 3 to run the script

Comment: Sorry for the question, but are u running the HTML page or the python script?

Comment: I am running the python script, when I try to run the HTML page I get an Internal Server Error

Answer (score 0):

So you are getting Internal Server Error (500)

that means the code of python you have written does work but when a request comes to the server an error occurs, or Flask just cant find your **index.html** file

by default Flask will search for your index.html file in a folder named `"templates"` or 
you can set the directory of your templates(HTML files) explicitly

Anyway I wrote this script for you, try to run it on your local machine

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__,
            static_url_path='', 
            static_folder='static',
            template_folder='myTemplates')

@app.route('/')
def mainRouter():
  return render_template("index.html")
```

You need to create a directory named `"myTemplates"` and put your index.html file inside it, you can change the name of course inside the script (`template_folder='myTemplates'`) to use another directory.

and if you have any static files, like images or audio files, videos, etc...
you need to create a directory called `"static"` and put all your static files there or you can change its name in the script (`static_folder='static'`) to whatever you like.

Comment: I see a lot of people complain about missing <!DOCTYPE html> and it's the reason you get that error, but in fact Flask doesn't know HTML and it's not supposed to, it's just sending the file to your browser, and it's up to the browser to render it, you can rewrite you index.html file to include no html tags, just `This can't be rendered right?!!` and of course you will have no errors and you will see that text on your browser normally

Comment: THANK YOU, I will try your script and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Add !DOCTYPE + HTML LANG.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<html lang="en-US">
        <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8" />
                <title>Home page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Home Page!</h1>
        <p>Hello!</p>


        </body>
</html>
```